# How to remove prev/next buttons from pagination function?

Tags: wordpress, function, pagination

I'm working with a custom function for page navigation in Wordpress, based on the one used in the Bones theme (http://themble.com/bones). The function outputs numbered page links, but also outputs both previous and next page buttons, even when you are on the first or last page. I want to adapt it to only show the previous page button when you are not on the first page, and only show the next page button when you are not on the last page. Hopefully that makes sense!

Here's the function:

```
function custom_page_navi($before = '', $after = '') {
global $wpdb, $wp_query;
$request = $wp_query->request;
$posts_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
$paged = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
$numposts = $wp_query->found_posts;
$max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
if ( $numposts <= $posts_per_page ) { return; }
if(empty($paged) || $paged == 0) {
    $paged = 1;
}
$pages_to_show = 7;
$pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show-1;
$half_page_start = floor($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
$half_page_end = ceil($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
$start_page = $paged - $half_page_start;
if($start_page <= 0) {
    $start_page = 1;
}
$end_page = $paged + $half_page_end;
if(($end_page - $start_page) != $pages_to_show_minus_1) {
    $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;
}
if($end_page > $max_page) {
    $start_page = $max_page - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
    $end_page = $max_page;
}
if($start_page <= 0) {
    $start_page = 1;
}
echo $before.'<nav class="pagination"><ol class="custom_page_navi">'."";
if ($start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $max_page) {
    $first_page_text = __( "First");
    echo '<li class="cpn-first-page-link"><a href="'.get_pagenum_link().'" title="'.$first_page_text.'">'.$first_page_text.'</a></li>';
}
echo '<li class="cpn-prev-link">';
previous_posts_link('');
echo '</li>';
for($i = $start_page; $i  <= $end_page; $i++) {
    if($i == $paged) {
        echo '<li class="cpn-current">'.$i.'</li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
}
echo '<li class="cpn-next-link">';
next_posts_link('');
echo '</li>';
if ($end_page < $max_page) {
    $last_page_text = __( "Last");
    echo '<li class="cpn-last-page-link"><a href="'.get_pagenum_link($max_page).'" title="'.$last_page_text.'">'.$last_page_text.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ol></nav>'.$after."";
```

}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just leave it? Also [Bones official Git](https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones) can be helpful, open a support issue there with this question. Anyways try this *untested code* :

Change this:

```
if ($end_page < $max_page) {
    $last_page_text = __( "Last", 'bonestheme' );
    echo '<li class="bpn-last-page-link"><a href="'.get_pagenum_link($max_page).'" title="'.$last_page_text.'">'.$last_page_text.'</a></li>';
}
```

To this:

```
if ($end_page < $max_page && != $max_page) {
    $last_page_text = __( "Last", 'bonestheme' );
    echo '<li class="bpn-last-page-link"><a href="'.get_pagenum_link($max_page).'" title="'.$last_page_text.'">'.$last_page_text.'</a></li>';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It's better for usability if only the relevant button is shown, as the other one doesn't do anything when inactive. Tried this code and unfortunately it came up with a server error.

Comment: Thanks for your help – still get a server error, so will try the Bones Github page.